# I have two branches in Github: main and production. for one server I want to make git pull default to production although it is not the default branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-pull

I have `main` and `production` branches in my GitHub repo.

I have 2 servers: one for production and the other for testing.

I want branches to match as follows:

```
main branch => testing server
production branch => production server
```

I have set up my ssh for both servers. I just want when I write: `git pull` in the production server to pull changes for the production branch, and when I write `git pull` in the testing server to pull changes from the main branch.

how can I do that?

I know I can pull the branch specifically but I want to make it automatic to prevent pulling testing changes to production by mistake.

Comment: What's your remotes setup here? (`git remote -v` should output the list)

Comment: @RomainValeri in my both production and testing server origin  [my-repo-link].git (fetch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this, in production server you can do (you should create production local branch if you have not)

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/production production
```

while , on testing server you can do:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main main
```

When you run `git pull` in each of them, they will retrive the updates from the right branches.

Comment: But it's more likely a multi-remote setup issue. You're assuming `origin` for both, but they should be different (whatever they're called in OP's real setup)